# Odd Scrolling Issue ( UIScrollView )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I have searched endlessly to no avail on this, hopefully someone can help!

I have a UIScrollView on the left half of a UIView which loads in custom cells/subviews. The UIView is part of a UINavigation stack, and it's also loaded into a tab on a TabBar.

What happens is, if I start the app and begin scrolling right away it's very smooth. However if I start the app and wait 5-10 seconds, the UIScrollView is VERY laggy and choppy (and it stays like that). I would think that it would be a memory leak or something, but I can't seem to find anything.

Included is the code of the view where I'm loading the custom cells/subviews into the UIScrollView. There isn't any custom code in the cell subview. Oh, and there's only about 8-10 items: each item has a small (150x150) image, and 3 text fields - all opaque.

```
    #import "ProductListViewController.h"
    #import "ProductListLeftItemViewController.h"


    @implementation ProductListViewController

    @synthesize listScroll;



    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *products = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        //  
        int numProducts;
        numProducts = [products count];
        [listScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, (numProducts * 111))];
        for (int i = 0; i < numProducts; i++) {
            ProductListLeftItemViewController *cellItem = [[ProductListLeftItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductListLeftItem" bundle:nil];
            cellItem.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (i*111), 500, 111);

            [self.listScroll addSubview:cellItem.view];
            cellItem = nil;
            [cellItem release];
        }
        [products release]; 

        [super viewDidLoad];

    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        NSLog(@"Memory warning, ProductListViewController");

        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


    - (void)dealloc {
        [listScroll release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

And as requested, the ProductListLeftItemViewController code:

```
#import "ProductListLeftItemViewController.h"


@implementation ProductListLeftItemViewController

@synthesize titleTxt, descriptionTxt, modelTxt, productThumb;


 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    titleTxt = nil;
    descriptionTxt = nil;
    modelTxt = nil;
    productThumb = nil;


    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [titleTxt release];
    [descriptionTxt release];
    [modelTxt release];
    [productThumb release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: are you loading the images from URL?

Comment: How many products do you have? Can you show us your ProductListLeftItemViewController? BTW calling release on cellItem after setting cellItem to nil is nonsense. You should swap these two lines.

Comment: Harinder: I wasn't loading the images from URL, in fact, I cleared the entire subview so that it was nothing but an opaque white background - same result.

Chiefly Izzy: Only 8 products, but I've even tried it with just 1 product, and with minimal information - same result. And thanks, I swapped the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has this problem in the future, once I started testing things on the actual device, everything worked perfectly smooth. Maybe it was just something quirky with the simulator? I'll consider this resolved, even though I'm still going to look into it a little further.